# Isn't this inheritance? If not please explain

Tags: java, inheritance

So if I instantiate a class in another class in Java, isn't that inheritance, because I am calling its method?

For example,

```
public void updateStock(int stockNew){
    stockFinal = stockNew;
    Stock stock = new Stock();
    stock.update(stockFinal);
}
```

Isn't that inheritance, because I am able to call the method, update().

Comment: No it's not. I'm not even sure how to answer this question because the problem quite literally just seems to be that you haven't actually read more about inheritance than the name.

Comment: Inheritance has to do with a class inheriting variables, methods, and constructors. Also, that code probably doesn't do what you think it does. You are instantiating a `Stock` but not storing it anywhere. You're just doing something to a variable that will be gone when the method ends.

Comment: You need to read a lot more about what `inheritance` really is...  However, if you're talking about calling a subclass method here, then it's a different aspect, but yes, there's a relationship.  Speaking deeply into the the different aspect, if `Stock`'s parent has a method called `update` and you inherited it in `Stock` then sure, this is called `inheriting a method`.

Answer (score 3):

This is inheritance:

```
 public class Base
 {
     public String Hello() {
          return "hello";
 }

 public class SubClass extends Base
 {
 }
```

Then it's used like this:

```
 SubClass sc = new SubClass();
 sc.Hello();   // returns "hello"
```

or

```
 Base b = new SubClass();
 b.Hello();  // calls the same as above
```

Or this, calling the base from an overridden method:

```
 public class SubClass extends Base
 {
    //@Override
    public String Hello(){
        return super.Hello() + " + override!!!";
    }
 }
```

The keyword `super` refers to the classes ancestor.

Answer (score 0):

No this is not inheritance. You are just calling the class itself.

Comment: but if I use 'inheritance' I can use its methods. Likewise, if I recall the class, I am able to use its method. So isn't that inheritance?

Comment: There is no relationship with calling a method and inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

No, using a class is not the same as inheriting the characteristics of a class.

See the [official Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) to learn more.

Comment: I am using its methods. So whats the difference?

Comment: @user3445748 If your class inherits from another class, your class **provides** the same methods that the class you're inheriting from provides.  And I'm sure you can understand the difference between "providing" methods and "using" methods.

Comment: @user3445748 I have updated my answer with a link to a Java Tutorial that you might find helpful.

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not inheritance. Inheritance is when a class *extends* another class. Inheritance is about establishing an is-a relationship, like a Car *is a* Vehicle. Or a List *is a* Collection.

In your example, you're just creating a new object or another type and calling a method on it. If you, of type Human, are using a car, of type Car, that doesn't make a Car a Human.

Answer (score 0):

No, that isn't inheritance. Inheritance is when a class `extends` or `implements` another class. For more information go [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/inheritance.html)

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://pankajtiwarii.blogspot.com/p/oops-abstraction-encapsulation.html)
You can find an explanation of what is OOP and its principles!

Answer (score 0):

This is not inheritance.
You are just creating a object of a class.
You can use method and data member of other class but object of base class can't use method or data member of your class.